# How to compare beans one without id and the retrieved with id field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, assert

I've created a new user in database but when I try to compare with the retrieved user idUser is different. The new idUser is 0, and the retreived is autoincrement.
idUser is the primary key of the table, and autoincrement.
username is unique.

JUnit code test

```
  @Test
  public void testCreateRetrieve() {
    userDao.create(user1);

    List<User> users = userDao.getAllUsers();

    assertEquals("One user should have been created and retrieved", 1, users.size());
    assertEquals("Inserted user should match user retreived", user1, users.get(0)); //They are not equal

    userDao.create(user2);
    userDao.create(user3);
    userDao.create(user4);

    assertEquals("Should be 4 inserted users", 4, users.size());
  }
```

Error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Inserted user should match user retreived expected:
<User [idUser=0, aka=joe, username=josema, email=jose@javalabs.com, extension=, logInSession=null, logOutSession=null, blockedAccess=false, password=josema, passwordDate=null, computerName=, timestamp=null]> 
but was:
<User [idUser=19, aka=joe, username=josema, email=jose@javalabs.com, extension=, logInSession=null, logOutSession=null, blockedAccess=false, password=josema, passwordDate=null, computerName=, timestamp=2014-03-31 12:37:41.0]>
```

How would I have to do the test? Or how can I check that users are the same?
Is the only way to do that override equals() and hashcode() methods?

Comment: please post your User entity with it's mapping

Answer (score 0):

You need to override equals() and hashCode() methods of your User class so it doesn't mind id while comparing. That is the best way. If you really don't want to override them you can just assert that properties are the same (i.e. name, email etc)